# How can I get Gmail searching to cope with bad spelling?

Tags: gmail, search

When I search for a word in Gmail I wish to find emails that contain misspellings of that word, as well as finding emails that contain the correct spelling of a  mis-spelt search.

The Google web search sometimes copes with this, but Gmail does not seem to.

---

I am looking for something like "sounds like".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of doing that in gmail. You can use OR in query to search for more than one word, but I don't think that this is what you want.